# Center a div in prestashop theme

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

What seems to be a simple task, I can't seem to make it work. 
If you look at http://www.ftina-pc.gr/demo/ near the footer I need to make the carousel header to center. 
I have added

```
#productTabs {    display: inline-block;}
.tab_wrapper {    text-align: center;}
```

This does center it but then I have problem with the width

I am trying to make it to look like 
[image]

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add

```
#productTabs > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add those styles to your li elements in #productTabs div (it's solution for bootstrap):

```
float: none;
display: inline-block;
```

You can also try to grab it into another div and add:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Another but not precise way is to push your first li element ~40% to right by adding left: X%; style.